# Auto form submission using jquery is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form using Jquery:

```
if(minute == 0 && hour==0) // minute is zero and hour is zero
            {       
                alert('here');
                var status = $.removeCookie("time",{'path': '/'}); 
                 $('#question_paper').submit(function(){
                    alert('works');
                 });
}
```

I can see the alert: 'here' which proves if condition is true after a time being but I can't see the alert: 'works' which proves form is not being submitted. My form is:

```
<form method="post" action="/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=active-exam&amp;exam_id=1" id="question_paper">
        <p></p><table class="bix-tbl-container" style="height: 40px" border="0" width="533" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="bix-td-qtxt" valign="top">If 60 J of energy are available for every 15 C of charge, what is the voltage?</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><p></p>
    <input name="opt1[]" type="checkbox" value="1">60 V <input name="opt1[]" type="checkbox" value="2">4 V  <input name="opt1[]" type="checkbox" value="3">15 V <input name="opt1[]" type="checkbox" value="4">.25 V    <hr>

    <p>Which resistive component is designed to be temperature sensitive?</p>
    <input name="opt2[]" type="checkbox" value="1">Rheostat <input name="opt2[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Thermistor   <input name="opt2[]" type="checkbox" value="3">Potentiometer    <input name="opt2[]" type="checkbox" value="4">Photoconductive cell <hr>

<input type="hidden" name="q_ids" value="1,2">
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="answer_sheet" id="answer_sheet_btn" class="button-primary" value="submit">
</p>

</form>
```

I checked:  No name attribute having 'submit' value. What is the problem?

Comment: If you pass a parameter to the submit function, it'll add an event listener o the submit event instead of triggering it. You can try `).trigger('submit');` or `).submit();` without parameters.

Comment: How is your function being triggered?

Comment: I am running a time down counter. When time is over then a form will be submitted. .submit is working for any event like click, hover but without any interaction I want to submit the form. @Matt Spinks

Comment: If I use submit() without any anonymous function as argument how can I pass form data and catch using php script? @Phiter

Comment: Well, the submit will push a request to the server updating the page. If  you want to do it without refreshing the page or changing the location, you can try using Ajax.

Comment: You do not have to choose between the two @AbdusSattarBhuiyan.  Assign your function to the submit event in the document load event.  Then follow the suggestion to call submit() without parameters when your timer fires, and what you have should work.

Comment: I want to do it with page refresh. So no need to use Ajax. But if I just use $('#question_paper').submit(); form is being submitted. But I can't detect it by checking  $_POST variable. Is there another approach? @phiter

Comment: If you submit it using .submit, you should get it in the server side by using $_POST.

Comment: It's the same thing as clicking the submit button inside the form

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phiter. You make my day. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your function to the submit event when the document is ready, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#question_paper').submit(function(){
                alert('works');
             });
    });
```

Then, as Phiter suggested, invoke your submit event without parameters when your timer fires:

```
$('#question_paper').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a parameter to the submit function, it'll add an event listener o the submit event instead of triggering it. You can try `).trigger('submit');` or `).submit();` without parameters.

If you want to have something happen when you submit the form, you should indeed add a event listener on page load, as suggested by Tom.

This will work as if you were clicking the submit button inside the form tag.